# Pass a hidden field value based on which button is clicked with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a form with two buttons, each with onclick = this.form.submit(). I have a hidden field in the form, and I would like the value of the field to be different based on which button is clicked. What would be the best way to do this?

Also, before anyone says it the answers, jQuery is not an option in this case.

Comment: If W3C fixed the submit input/button element, you wouldn't need JS or a hidden field. As things stand, the only way to do what you want without JS is to just use an image submit (make sure you include alt text for people using text-only browsers or screen readers).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use Prototype :-)

But in all seriousness:

1. Add an `id` to the hidden field
2. Before you submit the form in each handler:

   `document.getElementById("hiddenId").value = "mySpecialValue";`

   `//or (depending on which onclick handler you are in)`

   `document.getElementById("hiddenId").value = "myOtherSpecialValue";`
3. Submit the form the same way you are now.

Recommended ex:

`<input id="buttonA" type="button" value="do something" onclick="buttonA_clickHandler(event);"/>`

...

```
function buttonA_clickHandler(event) {
    document.getElementById('hiddenId').value = whatever;
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
}
```

repeat for the other button.

Comment: Can we make the 'use prototype' meme as prevalent on SO as the 'use jquery' one? ;)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you've got your hidden field setup something like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="clicked_button" id="clicked_button" value=""/>
```

You could just set its value in a common onclick handler for your buttons:

```
function buttonClick(theButton){
    document.getElementById('clicked_button').value = theButton.name;
    return true;
}
```

And then your submit buttons would be:

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick="return buttonClick(this)"/>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return buttonClick(this)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Forgive me if the answer to this
   seems obvious, but why use a hidden
   field at all? `<input type="submit"
   value="..." />` already works;
   browsers will send the `value` of
   the submit button that was clicked,
   along with the rest of the form
   data.
2. The `<button type="submit"
   name="..." value="...">...</button>`
   element works perfectly in
   Chrome/Safari/Firefox, but fails in
   IE7 (as Lèse majesté pointed out in
   his comment above); if you don't
   care about IE, that'd be the way to
   go.
3. You could also use an `<input type="image" />` 
   element, just remember that the browser submits 
   it as two fields: `name.x` and `name.y`. Also, 
   you can't set its value, but that shouldn't be a 
   problem if you're only interested in the 
   presence of the field.

Comment: The value property is also used to display the button text, so it's usually not a good candidate to carry data to the app.

Comment: True, but depending on the value the OP wants to send, it could still work. Also, the other two options are still valid.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the value to which you want to set the hidden input to a function you create:

```
function handleClick(val){
    document.getElementById('HiddenInputID').value = val;
    return true;
}
```

and then code the buttons using the `onclick` to pass whichever value you'd like:

```
<input type="submit" name="Name1" value="Value 1" onclick="return handleClick('Value 1')"/>
<input type="submit" name="Name2" value="Value 2" onclick="return handleClick('Value 2')"/>
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because submitting the form is also possible with JavaScript disabled which isn't the case with @geowa4's solution