# PHP Delete, Edit, Save Post

Tags: php, post, save, edit

I have queried my database and I have ID of a post as follows:

```
<?php
//Database query code is here. 
$post_id = $row['id'];

?>
```

I have added a form with buttons to each post so that when clicked, a corresponding function in the action.php file will be executed to out a string.
As follows

```
<form action = "action.php" method = "post">
<input type = "hidden" name = <?php echo "$post_id"?>">
<button type = "submit" name = "delete_post">Delete post </button>
<button type = "submit" name = "edit_post">Edit post </button>

<button type = "submit" name = "save_post">Save post </button>

</form>
```

And I have a PHP file containing several functions as follows

action.php

```
<?php

//first function

function delete_post($post_id){
if(isset($_POST["delete_post"])){
  $post_id = $_POST["$post_id"];
    echo " you attempted to delete the post, baby";
     }
}



//Second function

function edit_post($post_id){
if(isset($_POST["edit_post"])){
   $post_id = $_POST["$post_id"];
    echo "Hey you attempted to edit the post!";
     }
}

//Third function

function save_post($post_id){
if(isset($_POST["save_post"])){
   $post_id = $_POST["$post_id"];
    echo " Wow, did you really need to save that post?";
     }
}

delete_post($post_id);
edit_post($post_id);
save_post($post_id);

?>
```

What I want to achieve is that, for example, when delete_post button is clicked, only the 
 function delete_post($post_id) should be executed.

If edit_post button is clicked, only function edit_post($post_id) should be executed.

If save_post button is clicked only function save_post($post_id) should be executed.

But my code is not working. My problem is with the form and the action.php file. I wanted to pass the $post_id as parameter for the functions through URL when button is clicked but it's not working. I am a beginner and I have spent hours on this without success.

Comment: `_$POST` should be `$_POST`, what has been happening with it otherwise?

Comment: You need to first output `$post_id` in the form. Do a check for the named index and if present execute the appropriate function. `if(!empty($_POST[edit_post'])) { delete_post($_GET['post_id']; }` the hidden input also should have a static name, and a value, or you don't need it.

Comment: @kchason, Thanks for the correction. I have now changed <code> _POST   to <code> $_POST and after adding delete_post($post_id);
    edit_post($post_id);
    save_post($post_id);
It worked

Comment: @chris85 Thanks. That helped me a lot. My code then worked. However i needed the hidden input to have variable name not static

Comment: So you need to echo the variable, and put it in the valve, not the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems:

- You are calling `_$POST` instead of **[`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)**.
- In addition to the above, you shouldn't pass the dollar sign into the post:
  `_$POST["$save_post"]` should be `$_POST["save_post"]` for example.
- `<input ... name = "$post_id">` should have a proper ID. You need to actually  **output** `$post_id` here, rather than just write out the PHP variable. Remember; this is raw HTML; you're not inside a PHP block, so your ID is literally going to be just the string `$post_id`. To correct this, output the variable with `<input ... name = "<?php echo $post_id; ?>">`.
- You're not actually evoking any of your functions; you'll need to take your code outside of the functions, so that the three conditionals can all trigger independently:

```
if(isset($_POST["delete_post"])){
    $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];
    echo " you attempted to delete the post, baby";
}

if(isset($_POST["edit_post"])){
   $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];
   echo "Hey you attempted to edit the post!";
}

if(isset($_POST["save_post"])){
   $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];
   echo " Wow, did you really need to save that post?";
}
```

Or ensure that you call all three of the functions on page load:

```
function delete_post(){ ... }
function edit_post(){ ... }
function save_post(){ ... }

delete_post();
edit_post();
save_post();
```

Note that none of these three functions need any function parameters, as you're defining `$post_id` inside the functions themselves.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the response. That was helpful. However, you did not point out that  _$POST needed to be $_POST and "$save_post"  had to be "save_post"  in _$POST["$save_post"] without the dollar sign. This was pointed out in earlier comments. I just added the correct so another beginner may not be confused

Comment: My very first bullet point states that `_$POST` needs to be `$_POST`. But yes, you are looking for `$_POST["save_post"]`. While I mentioned the correction in the bullet point, Id forgotten to actually update the *code*. I've corrected this now :)

Comment: It also will be hard to identify `<input ... name = "<?php echo $post_id; ?>">` without looping the `$_POST`, I'd recommend moving that to the `value` and using a static name.

Comment: @chris85, actually each post retrieved from the database will have its own ID and the function will use the ID to delete, edit or save that post. If I make the <input type =" hidden" name = "static_id" ...>, then the function will delete all posts that have name = "static_id" but I want only a targeted post to be deleted, edit or saved at a type. This is why I needed a post to have variable name = "$post_id"

Comment: @ElizabethKof Still don't know how you are accessing that, wouldn't `$_POST['static_id']` be easier than `foreach($_POST as $name => $useless)  { if ($name == 'what you are checking'); }}`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @chris85 for the encouragement to re-read the question.

The following are the input form and the functions to support the form.

**input_form.php**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="action.php" method="post">
   <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="$post_id">' ?>
   <input type="radio" name="action" value="delete_post">Delete
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="action" value="edit_post">Edit
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="action" value="save_post">Save
   <br>
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php

if ( ! isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
   // Handle the case if $_POST['post_id'] is not set
}

if ( ! isset($_POST['action']) ) {
   // Handle the case if $_POST['action'] is not set
}

# Print the input we got
echo $_POST['post_id'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST['action'];
echo '<br>';

if ( $_POST['action'] === 'delete_post' ) {
   delete_post($_POST['post_id']);
}
elseif ( $_POST['action'] === 'edit_post' ) {
   edit_post($_POST['post_id']);
}
elseif ( $_POST['action'] === 'save_post' ) {
   save_post($_POST['post_id']);
}

//first function
function delete_post($post_id){
    echo " you attempted to delete the post, baby";
}

//Second function
function edit_post($post_id){
    echo "Hey you attempted to edit the post!";
}

//Third function
function save_post($post_id){
    echo " Wow, did you really need to save that post?";
}

?>
```

Hope this help!

---

In your original code, you have a separate button for each action type (i.e., one for delete, edit, and save). If you strongly desire to have multiple buttons instead of radio buttons, I would suggest the following JavaScript answer: [Pass a hidden field value based on which button is clicked with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550425/pass-a-hidden-field-value-based-on-which-button-is-clicked-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, your method works but actually I need three buttons there

Answer (score 0):

You have to receive the itens from the form, and execute a if statment.

```
<form action = "action.php?post_id=$post_id" method = "post">
    <input type="hidden" name = "$post_id">
    <button type="submit" name="delete_post" value="delete_post">Delete post </button>
    <button type="submit" name="edit_post" value="edit_post">Edit post </button>
    <button type="submit" name="save_post" value="save_post">Save post </button>
</form>
```

And in the PHP, something like this (atention, you must protect against SQL injection!!!):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //something posted

    if (isset($_POST['delete_post'])) {
        // delete_post code
    } else if (isset($_POST['edit_post'])) {
        //edit_post code
    } else {
        // save_post code
    }
}
```